# Carnot cycle equation

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

How to prove the relation

$\frac{Q_{given\space out}}{Q_{absorbed}}=\frac{T_{cold}}{T_{hot}}$

by only writing equations using first law?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @ChesterMiller No it is not. I was reading about carnot cycle and came across this equation. I tried but was not able to derive this equation using first law. So, I was hoping someone in SE could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're asking can be done.  Start at state 1 ($T_h,V_1$) and let the gas expand from $V_1$ to $V_2$ at constant $T_h$.  This determines $Q_h$.  Then let the gas expand from $V_2$ to $V_3$ adiabatically and reversibly.  This determines $T_c$.  Then compress at constant $T_c$ from $V_3$ to $V_4$. This determines $Q_c$. $V_4$ has to be such that, if you next compress adiabatically and reversibly from $V_4$ to $V_1$, the final temperature is $T_h$.  You need to solve for the value of $V_4$ that satisfies this constraint. Once this analysis is complete, the heat flows and temperatures should satisfy your desired equation.

Comment: While you can check that the relation is coincidentally true using the ideal gas temperature scale, it's worth pointing out that the result is actually general, and holds independently of the working substance (it can be thought of as a special choice of temperature scale).